# Get email of users installing my Google Sheet Add on

Tags: google-apps-script

We created a google sheet add on, and would like to communicate with people who installed it.

We know how to get the user's email after he opens the sheet for the first time, but we're trying to get the email when he accepts the scopes.

Is it possible ? i can't find any related doc on the google sites.

Thanks !

Comment: I'm sorry to be messaging you like this.  I'm a amateur developer, but I have been working on a Doc Add-on and I can't figure out the last steps to get it ready to publish.  I was hoping a conversation off line with you might help me get it published for distribution.

Comment: `We know how to get the user's email after he opens the sheet for the first time` How are currently you doing this? Are you using [getActiveUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())? Consider providing more details about your situation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure that your application is requesting the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scope.

Then, when authenticating with OAuth and requesting the access token the response will also include an `id_token` field. The response will look something like this:

```
{
  "access_token": <the access token>, 
  "id_token": <a long id token>, 
  "expires_in": 3599, 
  "token_type": "Bearer", 
  "scope": "openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email <other scopes>", 
  "refresh_token": <the refresh token>
}
```

Afterwards you can use the Google endpoint `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=<your id token>` to decode the id_token. It will return a JSON object like this:

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com", // The JWT's issuer
  "nbf":  161803398874,
  "aud": "314159265-pi.apps.googleusercontent.com", // Your server's client ID
  "sub": "3141592653589793238", // The unique ID of the user's Google Account
  "hd": "gmail.com", // If present, the host domain of the user's GSuite email address
  "email": "elisa.g.beckett@gmail.com", // The user's email address
  "email_verified": true, // true, if Google has verified the email address
  "azp": "314159265-pi.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "name": "Elisa Beckett",
                            // If present, a URL to user's profile picture
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/e2718281828459045235360uler",
  "given_name": "Elisa",
  "family_name": "Beckett",
  "iat": 1596474000, // Unix timestamp of the assertion's creation time
  "exp": 1596477600, // Unix timestamp of the assertion's expiration time
  "jti": "abc161803398874def"
}
```

From here you can grab the email field for your own purposes.

The `id_token` is a [JSON Web Token (JWT)](https://jwt.io/) string so you can also use other tools to decode it, not just the Google endpoint.

You can test this yourself with the scope above in Google's [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) too.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#credential

Comment: Thanks @Daniel ! It seems that we can't get the token until the user opens the google sheet. is that correct ?

Comment: Hi, what sheet are you referring to? Essentially you should get this token after the user installs your app and clicks 'Allow' in the OAuth consent screen, so it's when they accept the scopes.

Comment: It generates the token but I cannot get it until I access it in an appscript function